# Do we get more homework questions on economics than on statistics? If so, why?

Tags: discussion

I am active both on economics and cross-validated stackexchange and I've noted a LOT more homework questions at this site (including a lot of effort-less ones), than on cross-validated.

Given that, in my experience, many students struggle with both economics (especially micro) and stats I wonder why that is.

- Are students of economics more lazy ([Robert Frank has shown that studying economics makes you more self-interested](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2138205?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))?
- Does the cross-validated content look so technical that it scares beginner's questions away?
- Does cross-validated have a better filter system, or a more active
  community down-voting questions before I even see them?

Or are am I simply overlooking something else?

Comment: The proportion of homework-type questions on Economics SE is certainly higher than on Cross-Validated SE (because the latter has many more higher-level questions).  But is there any evidence that the absolute number is higher?

Comment: Well, I am interested in proportions, as it seems the only fair base of comparison given the sheer amount of questions and the difference between CV and Econ. I did try to fiddle around a bit with the SEDE for more quant answers, but my inexperience with queries blocks me from looking into the details. A simple search for homework on both econ and CV certainly returns more hits on the latter (48 vs 631), but as I said it's hardly fair to compare absolute numbers. There are 5234 questions here and roughly 112000  on CV, so that makes 0.9% and 0.5% respectively. Very rough of course

Comment: I would argue that absolute number is a more interesting comparison.  The main issue here is that because Economics SE has far fewer higher-level questions, its homework-type questions seem to have more prominence.

Comment: Could it be that the name of the website itself can cause this? If it would be "Statistics Stack exchange" would it attract more homework users?

Comment: @JoaoBotelho Possibly, although it would be hard to test :). In fairness though I doubt it. Given that the URL is http://stats.stackexchange.com/ it seems pretty clear to me that is the stats forum. Then again people might be scared of some of the high level discussions going on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to say whether we get more homework questions or not. However, a look at the statistics might suggest we don't:

- The first post in CV was in [Feb 2009](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/what-do-you-call-an-average-that-does-not-include-outliers), which is 103 months ago. The first post here was in [Nov 2014](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-isnt-there-an-ideal-value-for-a-given-currency), which is 34 months ago.
- CV has [63,100](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) closed questions as of today. We have [7,307](https://economics.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats).

So, while we have existed 33% of CV's lifespan, we have got 12% of their closed votes numbers.

Surely, a more definitive analysis would require a breakdown in terms of type of closure (which maybe can be produced with a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)).

PS: CV has a widely used [self-study tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study), which has 4,900 questions. That is around 95% the total number of questions that we have got. So in terms of volume, they might get more **on-topic** homework type questions. This does not tell us however about off-topic homework type questions.